# Histogram charts rendering away from data

Tags: qgis, alignment, histogram

I am having issues with producing Histograms in my file. Initially I thought they were not showing up, but it turns out they are, just extremely far away from my actual data. For reference:

[image: Histogram]

Here are the attributes I have set up. Is there anything in here that could be causing this issue? Is it possible that there is something else going on that is causing this to happen?

[image: Properties]

[image: Appearance]

[image: Size]

[image: Placement]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.